# Cannot access Docker --build-arg from RUN command (exec form)

Tags: docker, build, arguments, execl

I'm trying to use a `--build-arg` in one of my run statements, but it is failing.

**`Dockerfile`**

```
ARG OS_VERSION
...
RUN ["node", "./bin/installtoolchain.js", "${OS_VERSION}"]
```

I build the image using the following command:

```sh
docker build --tag installer --build-arg OS_VERSION=9 .
```

The script is failing, because it is passing the variable name instead of the value.

```
Error: Invalid toolchain configuration settings! Received: {
    "firmwareVersion": "${OS_VERSION}"
}
...
```

Why isn't my `--build-arg` being utilized?

Comment: In the Dockerfile reference, I found that the [exec form of the RUN instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) does not execute the shell, which is expected. But it does not mention that there is no way to expand the args without a shell, which is surprising! When I tried not including the quotes around variable expansion (`RUN ["node", "./bin/installtoolchain.js", ${OS_VERSION}]`), it failed to be parsed as the exec form. It was treated as the shell form, producing a confusing error message.

Answer (score 3):

Docker is failing to expand your argument by design.

Loosely speaking, Docker treats `--build-args` as temporary environment variables. Using an environment variable with the syntax `${VARIABLE}` requires shell expansion.

You have explicitly bypassed the shell, by using the exec form of the `RUN` command.

If you wish to utilize the `--build-arg`, then you must use the shell form of the `RUN` command.

```
RUN node ./bin/installtoolchain.js ${OS_VERSION}
```

or, to be precise, invoke the command from a shell.

```
RUN ["bash", "-c", "node ./bin/installtoolchain.js ${OS_VERSION}"]
```

Comment: Adding double quotes around `${OS_VERSION}` may be a good idea. The variable is designed not to contain any special characters but better be sure its contents is passed as is, without interpretation by the shell.

Comment: So the expansion of args is really the feature of a shell and Docker has no direct support for that? In the [ARG variables usage reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables), the relation to environment variables is discussed, but all the examples use the shell form and the exec form is not discussed at all. :-(